# Unable to set variable from File.ReadLines

Tags: vb.net

I need to read values from a file and set them as variables in order to connect to a database but when I try to set the variables from the file values, the program crashes.
I tried MsgBox, the values are correct..

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("config.ini")
    tmp_line = Split(line, "=")
    Select Case tmp_line(0)
        Case "dbname"
            dbname = tmp_line(1)
        Case "user"
            dbuser = tmp_line(1)
        Case "password"
            dbpasswd = tmp_line(1)
    End Select
Next line
```

They are both strings.

Any idea why ?
Thanks

Comment: Crashes with what error message and where?

Comment: what is the error msg you receive? I guess you are getting the same value for dbname,dbuser,dbpasswd, where your computer unable to locate the server.

Comment: My error is : "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".
I haven't tried to connect yet, just getting settings

Comment: Is there inner exception?

Comment: Yep, it says make sure that the types are the same, they are.

Comment: it can't hurt for you to include the declaration of tmp_line, dbname, dbuser and dbpasswd

Comment: They are all declared